# Excel: combine data duplicate email with latest date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have thousand email list with subscription end date and contact.
Each row has no complete data.
Example row 2 for a@gmail.com has no contact detail but row 3 a@gmail.com has contact.
How do I sort them into the right table as image below?

[image]

Comment: If any answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `D2` I would put this array formula (entered using **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**):

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$7=A2)*($B$2:$B$7<>""),0))
```

[image]

In `E2` this regular formula:

```
=MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,A2)
```

Or this array formula (entered using **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**):

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$7=A2,$C$2:$C$7,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 with the `FILTER`, `UNIQUE`, and `TEXTJOIN` functions, you can use these formulas:

*Note that I have used a Table with structured references, but you can convert that to mormal addressing if you prefer*

```
email:    =SORT(UNIQUE(Table1[email]))
Contact:  =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[Contact],(Table1[email]=I2))))
expired:  =MAXIFS(Table1[expired],Table1[email],I2)
```

`email` formula will `SPILL` down.  Other formulas must be filled/dragged down.

`Contact` will concatenate multiple contacts if they are different, otherwise will return just a single contact.

[image]

If you do not have those functions, you can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel.

You will have to **Refresh** the query if you make changes in the data table.

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"email", type text}, {"Contact", type text}, {"expired", type date}}),

//Group by Email
//  "Contact" line not available from the UI
//  If there are multiple, **different** contacts, they will all be returned
//    otherwise just the unique contact will be returned
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"email"}, {
        {"Contact", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([Contact]),", ")},
        {"Expired", each List.Max([expired]), type nullable date}       
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions are good for extensive filtering on a regular basis. For a simple solution, I would multi-column sort, first by email then by expiry (ascending). Then create a "latest contact" column with formula

```
=IF(B2="",B1,B2)
```

Then create a "latest expiry" column

```
=IF(C2="",C1,C2)
```

Then create "duplicates" column

```
=IF(A2=A3,"duplicate","final")
```

Now filter for all "final" rows, and copy and paste to a new sheet if you wish.